# autocomplete with jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code working,

```
$(function() {
    $("#student").autocomplete({
        source: "search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
```

it is the old way of doing it, i want to implement the new feature with `cache` enabled and also need to add the add the change event when i try to change something in the input field, it should detect it and i can create my action which can be adding an alert or anything

[image: stion with an image]

Updated my Question with an Image, also i tried using the course and select tags and changed it a bit to make it work, but i am still missing the part where i once selected , start removing the values from the selected input and want that the button below it should hide because i started editing the values just like the propertychange value of internet explorer, but can't change that property because it is internet specific

Comment: Not aware of any Caching options for Autocomplete. Can you please link to your reference? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Your update helps but it is not complete. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also your `search.php` should be returning result set that is filtered based on the `term` being sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```
$(function(){
  var cache = {};
  $("#student").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp){
      var term = req.term
      if(!(term in cache)){
        $.getJSON("search.php", req, function(data){
          cache[term] = data;
        });
      }
      resp(cache[term]);
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      $('#id').val(ui.item.id);
    }
  });
});
```

This will build a `cache` and populates that object on each lookup. If a term has been search before, it will just present the cached results.